# A question such as "Why make it bigger if it works as is?". How is this question understood better?

Tags: as

A question such as "Why make it bigger if it works as is?".

This usage has "as is" in this sentence.

It looke a bit confusing.

Is there any word omitted?

What is the purpose of this kind of usage?

========
I have some response to comment below

How about using "does" insteas of "is"?

that is,

A)"Why make it bigger if it works the way it does now?

or

B)"Why make it bigger if it works as the way as it does now?

Are both A) and B) acceptable and correct in grammar?

How is this question understood better?

==============

I looked up Practical English Usage also.
I guess that "as" can replace subject.
It sounds like an explanation of how as is used.
that is easily understood.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511019/than-and-as-as-subject-singular-or-plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct as written (except that "as-is" should properly be hyphenated). But there *is* a word missing: it means "as **it** is," i.e. in its current state or condition. Somewhere over time, the "it" was dropped, and "as-is" is accepted usage and appears in dictionaries. So we can understand the sentence as:

> Why make it bigger if it works the way it is now?

Comment: Is it okay to say "Why make it bigger if it works as the way as it does now?"?

Comment: @StatsCruncher No, that's not grammatical. "... if it works the way it does now" is grammatical but awkward due to a slight mismatch in meaning (_does_ should really be _is_, as I wrote it above).

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_3#as_idmg_6

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-it-is-as-it-turns-out-as-things-stand

Comment: @StatsCruncher Those links describe a different usage, and it's unclear why posted them.

Comment: I thought those two links of dictionaries explain the same meaning as you did. Am I misunderstood?